# Replace number in a part of a string based on a numeric condition and manipulate numerically cases with neighbours

Tags: replacement, string-manipulation

I want to replace numbers in a string based on a numeric condition.
Let us suppose the following string

"xxxx250 123|1,4|0,5|1,17|0,55|1,111|0"

I want to replace those numbers that are part of a pattern "X|1“ and where X>50.
Hence in my case, this would be "123" and "55".
Then, I want to replace "123|1" and "55|1“ by "127|0" and "166|0“, hence by the sum of 123 or 55 and the next number before the next |0, hence 4 or 111 and the "|1" by "|0".
The result should be

"xxxx250 127|0,5|1,17|0,166|0"

Any ideas?

Comment: The pattern X|1 will never happen twice without some X|0 in between?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string = "xxxx250 123|1,4|0,5|1,17|0,55|1,111|0";

StringReplace[string, n1 : NumberString ~~ "|1" ~~ "," ~~ n2 : NumberString ~~ "|0" /; 
   ToExpression[n1] > 50 :> ToString[ToExpression[n1] + ToExpression[n2]] <> "|0"]
```

> ```
> "xxxx250 127|0,5|1,17|0,166|0"
> ```

Comment: THANKS A LOT. It works.

Comment: @dirksaller, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept and Welcome to mma.se.